# Is there any information about the possibility of creation entity records in EntityMetadata?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

Here is the documentation [EntityMetadata EntityType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/entitymetadata?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9) where all the properties of an entity are described.
I can not find any property that can describe the possibility to create a record of this entity type there.
How can I figure out that this entity type supports the creation of records?
As an example - [activitypointer EntityType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/activitypointer?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9) supports only `Operations Supported GET`, but in the entity metadata description, there is nothing related to it.

> **ActivityPointer EntityMetadata**

```
{
  "ActivityTypeMask": 1,
  "AutoCreateAccessTeams": false,
  "AutoRouteToOwnerQueue": false,
  "CanBeInCustomEntityAssociation": {
    "CanBeChanged": false,
    "ManagedPropertyLogicalName": "canbeincustomentityassociation",
    "Value": false
  },
  "CanBeInManyToMany": {
    "CanBeChanged": false,
    "ManagedPropertyLogicalName": "canbeinmanytomany",
    "Value": false
  },
  "CanBePrimaryEntityInRelationship": {
    "CanBeChanged": false,
    "ManagedPropertyLogicalName": "canbeprimaryentityinrelationship",
    "Value": false
  },
  "CanBeRelatedEntityInRelationship": {
    "CanBeChanged": false,
    "ManagedPropertyLogicalName": "canberelatedentityinrelationship",
    "Value": false
  },
  "CanChangeHierarchicalRelationship": {
    "CanBeChanged": false,
    "ManagedPropertyLogicalName": "canchangehierarchicalrelationship",
    "Value": false
  },
  "CanChangeTrackingBeEnabled": {
    "CanBeChanged": true,
    "ManagedPropertyLogicalName": "canchangetrackingbeenabled",
    "Value": true
  },
  "CanCreateAttributes": {
    "CanBeChanged": false,
    "ManagedPropertyLogicalName": "cancreateattributes",
    "Value": false
  },
  "CanCreateCharts": {
    "CanBeChanged": false,
    "ManagedPropertyLogicalName": "cancreatecharts",
    "Value": true
  },
  "CanCreateForms": {
    "CanBeChanged": false,
    "ManagedPropertyLogicalName": "cancreateforms",
    "Value": false
  },
  "CanCreateViews": {
    "CanBeChanged": false,
    "ManagedPropertyLogicalName": "cancreateviews",
    "Value": true
  },
  "CanEnableSyncToExternalSearchIndex": {
    "CanBeChanged": false,
    "ManagedPropertyLogicalName": "canenablesynctoexternalsearchindex",
    "Value": false
  },
  "CanModifyAdditionalSettings": {
    "CanBeChanged": true,
    "ManagedPropertyLogicalName": "canmodifyadditionalsettings",
    "Value": true
  },
  "CanTriggerWorkflow": false,
  "ChangeTrackingEnabled": true,
  "CollectionSchemaName": "ActivityPointers",
  "DataProviderId": null,
  "DataSourceId": null,
  "DaysSinceRecordLastModified": 0,
  "Description": {
    "LocalizedLabels": [
      {
        "HasChanged": null,
        "IsManaged": true,
        "Label": "Task performed, or to be performed, by a user. An activity is any action for which an entry can be made on a calendar.",
        "LanguageCode": 1033,
        "MetadataId": "499709b3-2241-db11-898a-0007e9e17ebd"
      }
    ],
    "UserLocalizedLabel": {
      "HasChanged": null,
      "IsManaged": true,
      "Label": "Task performed, or to be performed, by a user. An activity is any action for which an entry can be made on a calendar.",
      "LanguageCode": 1033,
      "MetadataId": "499709b3-2241-db11-898a-0007e9e17ebd"
    }
  },
  "DisplayCollectionName": {
    "LocalizedLabels": [
      {
        "HasChanged": null,
        "IsManaged": true,
        "Label": "Activities",
        "LanguageCode": 1033,
        "MetadataId": "4b9709b3-2241-db11-898a-0007e9e17ebd"
      }
    ],
    "UserLocalizedLabel": {
      "HasChanged": null,
      "IsManaged": true,
      "Label": "Activities",
      "LanguageCode": 1033,
      "MetadataId": "4b9709b3-2241-db11-898a-0007e9e17ebd"
    }
  },
  "DisplayName": {
    "LocalizedLabels": [
      {
        "HasChanged": null,
        "IsManaged": true,
        "Label": "Activity",
        "LanguageCode": 1033,
        "MetadataId": "4a9709b3-2241-db11-898a-0007e9e17ebd"
      }
    ],
    "UserLocalizedLabel": {
      "HasChanged": null,
      "IsManaged": true,
      "Label": "Activity",
      "LanguageCode": 1033,
      "MetadataId": "4a9709b3-2241-db11-898a-0007e9e17ebd"
    }
  },
  "EnforceStateTransitions": false,
  "EntityColor": "#505050",
  "EntityHelpUrl": null,
  "EntityHelpUrlEnabled": false,
  "EntitySetName": "activitypointers",
  "ExternalCollectionName": null,
  "ExternalName": null,
  "HasActivities": false,
  "HasChanged": null,
  "HasFeedback": false,
  "HasNotes": false,
  "IconLargeName": null,
  "IconMediumName": null,
  "IconSmallName": null,
  "IconVectorName": null,
  "IntroducedVersion": "5.0.0.0",
  "IsAIRUpdated": false,
  "IsActivity": false,
  "IsActivityParty": false,
  "IsAuditEnabled": {
    "CanBeChanged": false,
    "ManagedPropertyLogicalName": "canmodifyauditsettings",
    "Value": false
  },
  "IsAvailableOffline": true,
  "IsBPFEntity": false,
  "IsBusinessProcessEnabled": false,
  "IsChildEntity": false,
  "IsConnectionsEnabled": {
    "CanBeChanged": false,
    "ManagedPropertyLogicalName": "canmodifyconnectionsettings",
    "Value": true
  },
  "IsCustomEntity": false,
  "IsCustomizable": {
    "CanBeChanged": false,
    "ManagedPropertyLogicalName": "iscustomizable",
    "Value": true
  },
  "IsDocumentManagementEnabled": false,
  "IsDocumentRecommendationsEnabled": false,
  "IsDuplicateDetectionEnabled": {
    "CanBeChanged": false,
    "ManagedPropertyLogicalName": "canmodifyduplicatedetectionsettings",
    "Value": false
  },
  "IsEnabledForCharts": true,
  "IsEnabledForExternalChannels": false,
  "IsEnabledForTrace": false,
  "IsImportable": false,
  "IsInteractionCentricEnabled": true,
  "IsIntersect": false,
  "IsKnowledgeManagementEnabled": false,
  "IsLogicalEntity": false,
  "IsMSTeamsIntegrationEnabled": false,
  "IsMailMergeEnabled": {
    "CanBeChanged": false,
    "ManagedPropertyLogicalName": "canmodifymailmergesettings",
    "Value": false
  },
  "IsManaged": true,
  "IsMappable": {
    "CanBeChanged": false,
    "ManagedPropertyLogicalName": "ismappable",
    "Value": false
  },
  "IsOfflineInMobileClient": {
    "CanBeChanged": false,
    "ManagedPropertyLogicalName": "canmodifymobileclientoffline",
    "Value": false
  },
  "IsOneNoteIntegrationEnabled": false,
  "IsOptimisticConcurrencyEnabled": true,
  "IsPrivate": false,
  "IsQuickCreateEnabled": false,
  "IsReadOnlyInMobileClient": {
    "CanBeChanged": false,
    "ManagedPropertyLogicalName": "canmodifymobileclientreadonly",
    "Value": false
  },
  "IsReadingPaneEnabled": true,
  "IsRenameable": {
    "CanBeChanged": false,
    "ManagedPropertyLogicalName": "isrenameable",
    "Value": true
  },
  "IsSLAEnabled": false,
  "IsSolutionAware": false,
  "IsStateModelAware": false,
  "IsValidForAdvancedFind": true,
  "IsValidForQueue": {
    "CanBeChanged": false,
    "ManagedPropertyLogicalName": "canmodifyqueuesettings",
    "Value": false
  },
  "IsVisibleInMobile": {
    "CanBeChanged": false,
    "ManagedPropertyLogicalName": "canmodifymobilevisibility",
    "Value": false
  },
  "IsVisibleInMobileClient": {
    "CanBeChanged": false,
    "ManagedPropertyLogicalName": "canmodifymobileclientvisibility",
    "Value": true
  },
  "LogicalCollectionName": "activitypointers",
  "LogicalName": "activitypointer",
  "MetadataId": "c821cd41-f315-43d1-8fa6-82787b6f06e7",
  "MobileOfflineFilters": "",
  "ObjectTypeCode": 4200,
  "OwnershipType": "UserOwned",
  "PrimaryIdAttribute": "activityid",
  "PrimaryImageAttribute": null,
  "PrimaryNameAttribute": "subject",
  "Privileges": [
    {
      "CanBeBasic": true,
      "CanBeDeep": true,
      "CanBeEntityReference": false,
      "CanBeGlobal": true,
      "CanBeLocal": true,
      "CanBeParentEntityReference": false,
      "Name": "prvCreateActivity",
      "PrivilegeId": "091df793-fe5e-44d4-b4ca-7e3f580c4664",
      "PrivilegeType": "Create"
    },
    {
      "CanBeBasic": true,
      "CanBeDeep": true,
      "CanBeEntityReference": false,
      "CanBeGlobal": true,
      "CanBeLocal": true,
      "CanBeParentEntityReference": false,
      "Name": "prvReadActivity",
      "PrivilegeId": "650c14fe-3521-45fe-a000-84138688e45d",
      "PrivilegeType": "Read"
    },
    {
      "CanBeBasic": true,
      "CanBeDeep": true,
      "CanBeEntityReference": false,
      "CanBeGlobal": true,
      "CanBeLocal": true,
      "CanBeParentEntityReference": false,
      "Name": "prvWriteActivity",
      "PrivilegeId": "0dc8f72c-57d5-4b4d-8892-fe6aac0e4b81",
      "PrivilegeType": "Write"
    },
    {
      "CanBeBasic": true,
      "CanBeDeep": true,
      "CanBeEntityReference": false,
      "CanBeGlobal": true,
      "CanBeLocal": true,
      "CanBeParentEntityReference": false,
      "Name": "prvDeleteActivity",
      "PrivilegeId": "bb4457f2-9b45-4482-a95a-7adef25f388a",
      "PrivilegeType": "Delete"
    },
    {
      "CanBeBasic": true,
      "CanBeDeep": true,
      "CanBeEntityReference": false,
      "CanBeGlobal": true,
      "CanBeLocal": true,
      "CanBeParentEntityReference": false,
      "Name": "prvAssignActivity",
      "PrivilegeId": "8b99344e-ebbf-4f84-8438-e1e34d194de9",
      "PrivilegeType": "Assign"
    },
    {
      "CanBeBasic": true,
      "CanBeDeep": true,
      "CanBeEntityReference": false,
      "CanBeGlobal": true,
      "CanBeLocal": true,
      "CanBeParentEntityReference": false,
      "Name": "prvShareActivity",
      "PrivilegeId": "b5f2ee06-d359-4495-bbda-312aae1c6b1e",
      "PrivilegeType": "Share"
    },
    {
      "CanBeBasic": true,
      "CanBeDeep": true,
      "CanBeEntityReference": false,
      "CanBeGlobal": true,
      "CanBeLocal": true,
      "CanBeParentEntityReference": false,
      "Name": "prvAppendActivity",
      "PrivilegeId": "78777c10-09ab-4326-b4c8-cf5729702937",
      "PrivilegeType": "Append"
    },
    {
      "CanBeBasic": true,
      "CanBeDeep": true,
      "CanBeEntityReference": false,
      "CanBeGlobal": true,
      "CanBeLocal": true,
      "CanBeParentEntityReference": false,
      "Name": "prvAppendToActivity",
      "PrivilegeId": "6ec8e901-d770-44c0-8f12-d07425f638bd",
      "PrivilegeType": "AppendTo"
    }
  ],
  "RecurrenceBaseEntityLogicalName": null,
  "ReportViewName": "FilteredActivityPointer",
  "SchemaName": "ActivityPointer",
  "SyncToExternalSearchIndex": false,
  "UsesBusinessDataLabelTable": false
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reviewed this and I agree that there is no explicit entity metadata attribute akin to `IsCreatable`.

You could wrap an attempt to `Create` an empty entity of the type in a `try` / `catch` block.

When I ran:

```
var pointer = new ActivityPointer();
pointer.Create(svc);
```

The service threw this exception, even though the `pointer` entity contains no attributes:

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1: 'The 'Create' method does not
>   support entities of type 'activitypointer'.'

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.createrequest?view=dynamics-general-ce-9) lists the entities that support the `IOrganizationService Create` method under "Supported Entities".
Here is the list:

```
Account  
ActivityMimeAttachment  
Annotation  
AnnualFiscalCalendar  
Appointment  
AsyncOperation  
AttributeMap  
BusinessUnit  
BusinessUnitNewsArticle  
Calendar  
Campaign  
CampaignActivity  
CampaignResponse  
ColumnMapping  
Competitor  
Connection  
ConnectionRole  
ConnectionRoleObjectTypeCode  
ConstraintBasedGroup  
Contact  
Contract  
ContractDetail  
ContractTemplate  
ConvertRule  
ConvertRuleItem  
CustomerAddress  
CustomerOpportunityRole  
CustomerRelationship  
Discount  
DiscountType  
DuplicateRule  
DuplicateRuleCondition  
DynamicProperty  
DynamicPropertyAssociation  
DynamicPropertyInstance  
DynamicPropertyOptionSetItem  
Email  
EmailServerProfile  
Entitlement  
EntitlementChannel  
EntitlementTemplate  
EntitlementTemplateChannel  
Equipment  
ExchangeSyncIdMapping  
Fax  
FieldPermission  
FieldSecurityProfile  
FixedMonthlyFiscalCalendar  
Goal  
GoalRollupQuery  
HierarchyRule  
HierarchySecurityConfiguration  
Import  
ImportEntityMapping  
ImportFile  
ImportJob  
ImportMap  
Incident  
IncidentResolution  
Invoice  
InvoiceDetail  
IsvConfig  
KbArticle  
KbArticleComment  
KbArticleTemplate  
Lead  
Letter  
List  
LookUpMapping  
Mailbox  
MailMergeTemplate  
Metric  
MonthlyFiscalCalendar  
msdyn_PostAlbum  
msdyn_PostConfig  
msdyn_PostRuleConfig  
msdyn_wallsavedquery  
msdyn_wallsavedqueryusersettings  
Opportunity  
OpportunityClose  
OpportunityProduct  
OrderClose  
OrganizationUI  
OwnerMapping  
PhoneCall  
PickListMapping  
PluginAssembly  
PluginType  
Position  
Post  
PostComment  
PostFollow  
PostLike  
PriceLevel  
PrincipalObjectAttributeAccess  
ProcessSession  
ProcessTrigger  
Product  
ProductAssociation  
ProductPriceLevel  
ProductSubstitute  
Publisher  
PublisherAddress  
QuarterlyFiscalCalendar  
Queue  
QueueItem  
Quote  
QuoteClose  
QuoteDetail  
RecurrenceRule  
RecurringAppointmentMaster  
RelationshipRole  
RelationshipRoleMap  
Report  
ReportCategory  
ReportEntity  
ReportVisibility  
ResourceSpec  
Role  
RollupField  
RoutingRule  
RoutingRuleItem  
SalesLiterature  
SalesLiteratureItem  
SalesOrder  
SalesOrderDetail  
SavedQuery  
SavedQueryVisualization  
SdkMessageProcessingStep  
SdkMessageProcessingStepImage  
SdkMessageProcessingStepSecureConfig  
SemiAnnualFiscalCalendar  
Service  
ServiceAppointment  
ServiceEndpoint  
SharePointDocument  
SharePointDocumentLocation  
SharePointSite  
Site  
SLA  
SLAItem  
SLAKPIInstance  
SocialActivity  
SocialInsightsConfiguration  
SocialProfile  
Solution  
Subject  
SystemForm  
SystemUser  
Task  
Team  
TeamTemplate  
Template  
Territory  
TraceLog  
TransactionCurrency  
TransformationMapping  
TransformationParameterMapping  
UoM  
UoMSchedule  
UserEntityInstanceData  
UserEntityUISettings  
UserForm  
UserQuery  
UserQueryVisualization  
WebResource  
Workflow  
WorkflowDependency  
WorkflowLog
```

Comment: I am using REST API, and this answer will not help me to distinguish which entities are creatable. I want to build a generic solution. To hardcode all the creatable entities is a bad idea. As far as I know, a number of entities can vary depending on different organizations.

Comment: If this is the only available solution, I will accept this answer :)

Comment: @Aron Thanks for the info, Even I was looking into it and could not find a way via REST to determine if IsCreateable and then my next thought was Server Side Plugin Messages which support Create. I think answer mentioned is the only way.